# Best sensor for breathing activity?

Tags: sensor

those who are much cleverer than me please help me with this.. Which sensor would be best suited for measuring the intensity of in and out of a person's breathing at rest when the sensor is to be positioned under his nose?

Answer (score 3):

Probably a thermistor to look at the temperature change between inhaled and exhaled breath would be easiest.  If you're really interested in flow, then a thermistor in self-heating mode to be cooled by inhales and exhales.  the latter is trickier, as inhaled and exhaled breath will be two different temps, so the flow sensitivity for each phase will probably be different.

Moving up the line, you can also look at chest inflation using skin plethysmography, which is essentially the broadcasting of a small sin wave, and looking at the reception at a distant location on the chest.  The sine wave should really be isolated.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I will explore down that path!

Answer (score 0):

Ultrasonic flow measurement may actually be the highest spatiotemporal resolution, the lowest cost, and fastest implementation time due its commercial availability.

It was used to great effect [in this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12412683) to monitor infants for congenital airway defects.

Comment: Sure, if you have the full airstream captured by a mask, that's one way to go.  You'd need all the air, or at least a constant fraction, moving through a tube for ultrasound.